# C++ program outputs memory address but only when used as a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, memory-management

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int numericMenu();
void newGrade(int*, int);

int main() {
  int choice = 0;
  int* gradePtr = nullptr;
  int size = 0;
  int i = 0;
  gradePtr = new int[size];

  
  
  do {
    choice = numericMenu();
    if (choice == 1)
    {
      newGrade(gradePtr, size);
    }

  } while(choice != 2);
  
  return 0;
}

int numericMenu(){
  int choice = 0;
  cout << "1. Add Grade\n";
  cout << "2. Quit Program \n";
  cin >> choice;
  return choice;
}

void newGrade(int* gradePtr, int size){
  int *pTemp = nullptr;
   
  pTemp = new int[size];

  for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    pTemp[i] = gradePtr[i];
  
  cout << "Enter score: ";
  cin >> pTemp[size];

  delete[] gradePtr;
  gradePtr = pTemp;
  pTemp = nullptr;

  for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    cout << gradePtr[i] << endl;
  size++;
}
```

I am working on an assignment to make a program that analyzes test scores. One of the requirements is creating our own dynamically sized array. We are not allowed to use anything from the standard template library.

It's supposed to simply allow the user to input a bunch of numbers that are stored in an array, then print the numbers back out. This code works fine when it is in main. When I try to make it into a function, it displays the first score and then displays a memory address.

Comment: `i <= size` should be `i < size` otherwise you'll access `size + 1` elements. As `size` is zero the array is empty and you can't use any elements from it

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. You always allocate zero elements, and you always pass the null pointer to `newGrade`.

Comment: You could make the parameters references: `void newGrade(int*& gradePtr, int& size)`

Comment: The `size++;` in the original code only affects the copy inside void newGrade, not the `size` in main. Similar problem for `gradePtr = ...`

Comment: Every time you get a new grade, you will copy previous items into a new array, delete the old one and make it point to the new array.

Comment: "We are not allowed to use anything from the standard template library" Alas, you are in a class that probably will not teach you much of C++. If your goal is to learn C++ you may want to consider going elsewhere. Failing that, if you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, you should *make your own simplified version*, rather than fiddling with naked pointers everywhere. Build it, test it, then use it in this assignment and any future assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different issues in the code. 
1- `gradePtr = new int[size];` you don't have to allocate it until it has size 
2- `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)` you have to rotate only size times so it should be from 0 to size-1 
3- `void newGrade(int* gradePtr, int size)` you are passing these parameters by copy them in order to update the versions in the main function you have to send them using refrence operator  `void newGrade(int* & gradePtr, int & size)`